# Printing values corresponding to the column index in r

Tags: r, matrix, row, latitude-longitude

I have a matrix 'index' with row and column numbers.

```
Row Column
    1   1746
    1   1867
    1   4631
    2   3
    2   26
    2   28
    2   34
    2   38
    2   47
    2   52
    2   59
    2   75
    2   78
    2   104
```

I have another matrix 'locations' consisting of 5000 rows of lat/long values.

```
   Row  longitude   latitude
    1   100.148995  18.147936
    2   98.968003   18.789907
    3   98.967501   18.796631
    4   98.924965   18.747545
    5   105.791758  21.218454
    6   105.851929  21.037073
    7   99.862961   20.130128
    8   102.825773  17.348081
    9   99.078912   18.84856
    10  102.825682  17.347978
    11  99.078871   18.848615
    12  98.931815   18.924331
    13  102.825634  17.347986
```

Now I want to find lat/long values of the row numbers in locations corresponding to the column number in index and join them in the form of a table which will look like this

```
Row  Column  Latitude                               Longitude
1   723     Latitude of Row#723 of 'locations'      Longitude of Row#723 of 'locations'
1   1746    Latitude of Row#1746 of 'locations'     Longitude of Row#1726 of 'locations'                                .                                      
1   1867      .                                         .
1   4631      .                                         .
2   3         98.967501                             18.796631
2   26
2   28
2   34
2   38
2   47
2   52
```

Similarly I want to get the locations corresponding to column numbers for all values. How do I do this in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `merge`, and tell R which ones we want to merge by:

```
merge (index, locations, by.x="Column", by.y="Row")
```

which for your test data gives:

```
  Column Row longitude latitude
1      3   2   98.9675 18.79663
```

Depending on what you want to happen if there is no match, you can also use `all = TRUE` in the call to include missing values. Check out `?merge` for more info.